# NestJs TypeORM configuration using env files

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I have two .env files like `dev.env` and `staging.env`. I am using typeorm as my database ORM. I would like to know how to let typeorm read either of the config file whenever I run the application. `Error: No connection options were found in any of configurations file` from typeormmodule.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can create a [ConfigService](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration) that reads in the file corresponding to the environment variable `NODE_ENV`:

1) Set the `NODE_ENV` variable in your start scripts:

```
"start:dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=dev ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register src/main.ts",
"start:staging": "cross-env NODE_ENV=staging node dist/src/main.js",
```

2) Read the corresponding .env file in the ConfigService

```
@Injectable()
export class ConfigService {
  private readonly envConfig: EnvConfig;

  constructor() {
    this.envConfig = dotenv.parse(fs.readFileSync(`${process.env.NODE_ENV}.env`));
  }

  get databaseHost(): string {
    return this.envConfig.DATABASE_HOST;
  }
}
```

3) Use the `ConfigService` to set up your database connection:

```
TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
  imports:[ConfigModule],
  useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
    type: configService.getDatabase()
    // ...
  }),
  inject: [ConfigService]
}),
```

Comment: in this approach you will need second configuration file in order to use typeorm CLI

Comment: Did you put this in the app.module.ts? I am getting errors saying `Error: No connection options were found in any of configurations file.`.

Comment: @rhlsthrm Yes, in `app.module.ts`. I haven't had an error like this, would need to look at this in more detail. If you can't solve it, maybe open a new question for it. :-)

Comment: @KimKern, thanks for the response. I opened a new question.

Comment: @grexlort is right, you will need a default export config file to use TypeORM CLI managing your migration for example. But this could be imported in your ConfigService as an exception or you can be generic and import them this way

Answer (score 0):

**1) i'm using `typeorm` to to use migration, but in this case i want to use two different folders for migrations(table structure) and seeds(default data to table)**

**2) so this is how i resolved this in `nestjs` with `typeorm`**

```
// config for typeorm and used for mysql driver also
import { DataSource, DataSourceOptions } from 'typeorm';
import { config } from 'dotenv';
config();
const { MYSQL_HOST, MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PASSWORD, MYSQL_DATABASE, PATH_TO_RUN 
} =
process.env;
export const dbConfig: DataSourceOptions = {
  type: 'mysql',
  host: MYSQL_HOST,
  port: 3306,
  username: MYSQL_USER,
  password: MYSQL_PASSWORD,
  database: MYSQL_DATABASE,
  entities: ['dist/**/*.entity.js'],
  migrations: [`dist/db/${PATH_TO_RUN}/*.js`], // update this path with env
};
export default new DataSource(dbConfig);
```

**3) package.json look like after using `cross-env` this for typeorm**

```
// DON'T PLACE `cross-env` in build script use it in `typeorm` execution script
script: {
"migration:run": "yarn build && cross-env PATH_TO_RUN=migrations yarn typeorm migration:run -d dist/db/mysql.config.js",
"seed:run": "yarn build && cross-env PATH_TO_RUN=seeds yarn typeorm migration:run -d dist/db/mysql.config.js"
}
```

**4) to run this npm script use this below command**

> yarn migration:run // to use migrations folder in typeorm
>
> yarn seed:run // to use seeds folder in typeorm

**!!  Before using Yarn and Cross-env please make sure it is installed  !!**

```
npm install --global yarn
yarn add cross-env
```