# NestJs: Unable to read env variables in module files but able in service files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs, dotenv

I have an `.env` file at the root of my NestJs project with some env variables in it.

The strange thing is that I am able to read the variables in service files but not in module files.

So in a service file like `users.service.ts`, this works:

```
saveAvatar() {
    const path = process.env.AVATAR_PATH    // returns value from .env
}
```

However, when accessing a path in a module file like `auth.module.ts`, this returns an empty value:

```
@Module({
    imports: [
       JwtModule.register({
          secretOrPrivateKey: process.env.SECRET   // process.env.SECRET returns an empty string
       })
    ]
})
```

Why is that so? How can I reliably access environmental variables in the `.env` file in NestJs?

Comment: Where (and when) are you reading in the `.env` file?

Comment: @KimKern I'm reading the file in a module file which resides in the module's folder. The .env file is in the root of the project. I've updated my question to show when they are used.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Your `.env` file is not yet read in when your `JwtModule` is instantiated. So either read it in earlier e.g. in your `main.ts` before the nest app is created or better: create a `ConfigService` and make the dependency on your config explicit:

```
JwtModule.registerAsync({
    imports: [ConfigModule],
    useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
      secret: configService.jwtSecret,
    }),
    inject: [ConfigService],
}),
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54364907/4694994) on how to create a `ConfigService`.

Comment: You can also use it this way: ```JwtModule.registerAsync({
      useFactory: async () => ({
        secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY,
        signOptions: { expiresIn: process.env.JWT_EXPIRATION_TIME },
      }),
    }),```. 
There is no need for a ConfigService to load environment variables. Use registerAsync with useFactory

Answer (score 9):

The declaring order is important in your use case.

This works:

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot(),
    ScheduleModule.forRoot(),
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'mongodb',
      host: process.env.SYN_MONGO_HOST,
      port: +process.env.SYN_MONGO_PORT,
      username: process.env.SYN_MONGO_USERNAME,
      password: process.env.SYN_MONGO_PASSWORD,
      database: process.env.SYN_MONGO_DATABASE,
      authSource: 'admin',
      autoLoadEntities: true,
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [],
})
export class ConfigurationModule {}
```

When this doesn't

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    ScheduleModule.forRoot(),
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'mongodb',
      host: process.env.SYN_MONGO_HOST,
      port: +process.env.SYN_MONGO_PORT,
      username: process.env.SYN_MONGO_USERNAME,
      password: process.env.SYN_MONGO_PASSWORD,
      database: process.env.SYN_MONGO_DATABASE,
      authSource: 'admin',
      autoLoadEntities: true,
    }),
    ConfigModule.forRoot(),
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [],
})
export class ConfigurationModule {}
```

This is because ConfigModule is load before or after TypeOrmModule.

Answer (score 6):

I just realize that I solve my problem also, just importing dotenv and calling the method config at the beginning of my module (auth.module.ts).

```
import dotenv from "dotenv";

dotenv.config({path:<path-to-env-file>})
```

No need to specify the path if you are using the default .env file at the root of the project.

Comment: Simple solution that solve my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Like @KimKen said, the problem is that, by the time that the JwtModule is instantiated the environment variables still are not loaded. However, I have a different approach to @KimKen's answer that you might also be interested in.

First of all NestJS provide a ConfigModule that load the environment variables, so you don't need to create one, unless you wish handle it different than the usual. (https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration)

Now, to solve the problem I made the module (auth.module.ts) dynamic.
In short words a dynamic module is module that receive parameters, and it depend on that input parameters for its right instantiation.(https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/dynamic-modules)

The real thing going on here, is that the JwtModule is also a dynamic module because it depend on a variable for its right instantiation. So, that cause that also your module depend on parameters for its right instantiation, so make it dynamic! :).

Then your auth.module will be something like:

```
@Module({})
export class AuthModule {

    static forRoot(): DynamicModule {
        return {
            imports: [
                JwtModule.register({
                    secretOrPrivateKey: process.env.SECRET   // process.env.SECRET will return the proper value
                })
            ],
            module: AuthModule
        }
    }
```

Then it will be as easy as in your app.module or where ever you load the auth.module import it through the forRoot static method.

```
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';

@Module({
    imports: [ConfigModule.forRoot(), AuthModule.forRoot()]
})
```

Note: I recommend import ConfigModule once in the app.module.ts

PD: You could make the dynamic auth.module receive a parameter in the forRoot method and in the app.module pass the environment variable `process.env.SECRET`

```
AuthModule.forRoot(process.env.SECRET)
```

but it seems that dynamic modules are loaded last so there is not need for that.

Answer (score 4):

You can use it as global for access from other modules.

> When you want to use ConfigModule in other modules, you'll need to
> import it (as is standard with any Nest module). Alternatively,
> declare it as a global module by setting the options object's isGlobal
> property to true, as shown below. In that case, you will not need to
> import ConfigModule in other modules once it's been loaded in the root
> module (e.g., AppModule)

.https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration#use-module-globally

```
ConfigModule.forRoot({
  isGlobal: true
});
```

Also you can find here how to use config service: https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration#using-the-configservice

Comment: @Kekson have you re-start app after set it? and please take care "ConfigModule is been loaded in the root module (e.g., AppModule)"

Comment: yes but restart did not help, in my app.module.ts i have set this ConfigModule.forRoot({ isGlobal: true }) and in other modules i have process.env.PORT but it still does not read from env

Comment: If i put ConfigModule.forRoot() in other modules imports as well as in AppModule (as isGlobal: true) than it works fine... seems weird but it works

Comment: @Kekson Other modules should be a child of your main module. If the other modules are not chield may you have define it again.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. Had written the code on another machine in which it ran fine. Cloned the repo onto another machine tried to run but hit the the env variables issue because I didn't have the .env file. Copied it across but still got the error message. Removing node_modules and installing followed by nom run build solved the issue for me

Answer (score 1):

I was having same problem, just configure your ConfigModule as mentioned in [NestJs Documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration#use-module-globally) but one more thing you have to add  `envFilePath:'.env'` in your `app.module.ts` as Below

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
  ConfigModule.forRoot({
    isGlobal: true,
    envFilePath:'.env',
  })
]
```

And to use **.env** variables you can use `process.env.VARIABLE_NAME`, if it is not working for you, then you have to use `configService.get('')` method as below code

```js
constructor(private readonly configService: ConfigService) {
        const secretKey =this.configService.get('STRIPE_SECRET_KEY');
        }
```

and make sure to save **.env** file in the root folder outside **src**.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the same issue by changing the import order: move 'dotenv/config' ahead of AppModule, as the following:

```
import 'dotenv/config'
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
```

Answer (score 0):

it is works for me

```js
@Module({
    imports: [ConfigModule.forRoot({
        envFilePath: join(process.cwd(), 'env', `.env.${process.env.SCOPE.trim()}`),
    })]
})
```

The solution is to use the `trim()` function because in Windows spaces are added to the end of the value of the environment variable

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Jetbrains IDE:

You may need to remove the `baseUrl` from your `tsconfig.json`. There is a [ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-62888/baseUrl-in-tsconfig.json-breaks-typings-resolving) related to this behavior. Removing 'baseUrl' is fine as long as you use `paths` instead, [according to docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#baseUrl) (TS version >= 4.1).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I just use the `import 'dotenv/config';` only in the `auth.module.ts` that solved my problem. I think the JwtModule is initialized before the ConfigModule (I see the log messages when start application), so it can not access the process.env.

Comment: but in some project you does't need to import config and install config it will work but in some nest project it will work. is any idea in as according to me in nest does not need to install env file

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, and solved by providing the JWT secret directly in the service, in the signAsync function, instead of trying to load the module dynamically.

Saves quite a lot of headaches.