# You did not provide an API key. You need to provide your API key in the Authorization header

Tags: reactjs, next.js, stripe-payments

im getting this error when i try to use the my checkout function using Stripe:

`You did not provide an API key. You need to provide your API key in the Authorization header, using Bearer auth (e.g. 'Authorization: Bearer YOUR_SECRET_KEY'). See https://stripe.com/docs/api#authentication for details, or we can help at https://support.stripe.com/.`

I also tried to use a if check to check for the stripe key, but i got an error that said the key did not exist .

**checkout function:**

```
const handleCheckOut = async () => {
    const stripe = await getStripe();

    const response = await fetch("/api/stripe", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY}`,
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(cartItems),
    });

    if (response.statusCode === 500) return;

    const data = await response.json();

    toast.loading("Redirecting...");

    stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId: data.id });
  };
```

Even though im passing the Stripe api secret key as Authorization header it is still not woking

**getStripe.js**

```
import { loadStripe } from "@stripe/stripe-js";

let stripePromise;

const getStripe = () => {
  if (!stripePromise) {
    stripePromise = loadStripe(`${process.env.STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY}`);
  }

  return stripePromise;
};

export default getStripe;
```

**api/stripe.js**

```
import Stripe from "stripe";

const stripe = new Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body.cartItems);
  if (req.method === "POST") {
    try {
      const params = {
        submit_type: "pay",
        mode: "payment",
        payment_method_type: ["card"],
        billing_address_collection: "auto",
        // formas de envio
        shipping_options: [
          { shipping_rate: "shr_1LJo2EHt0s8JSRoPQEDeHfo5" },
          { shipping_rate: "shr_1LJo3ZHt0s8JSRoP8uVNJhwS" },
        ],
        line_items: req.body.map((item) => {
          const img = item.image[0].asset._ref;
          const newImage = img
            .replace(
              "image-",
              "https://cdn.sanity.io/images/psdgq2wv/production/"
            )
            .replace("-webp", ".webp");

          return {
            price_data: {
              currency: "usd",
              product_data: {
                name: item.name,
                images: [newImage],
              },
              unit_amount: item.price * 100,
              adjustable_quantity: {
                enabled: true,
                minimum: 1,
              },
              quantity: item.quantity,
            },
          };
        }),
        // success_url: `${req.headers.origin}/?success=true`,
        // cancel_url: `${req.headers.origin}/?canceled=true`,
      };
      // Create Checkout Sessions from body params.
      const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create(params);
      res.status(200).json(session);
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(err.statusCode || 500).json(err.message);
    }
  } else {
    res.setHeader("Allow", "POST");
    res.status(405).end("Method Not Allowed");
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you proven to yourself that process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY exists

Comment: Add this just before the `fetch` call: `if (!process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY) throw new Error('process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY not found');`

Comment: can you pls share  the code written in`getStripe` and `api/stripe`

Comment: The if check threw the error. I dont know why.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that you need to send this: `Authorization:` Bearer ${process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY}`,`. I think the issue is here

```
const getStripe = () => {
  if (!stripePromise) {
    stripePromise = loadStripe(`${process.env.STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY}`);
  }

  return stripePromise;
};
```

since you are on client side, `process.env.STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY` will be undefined. because by default environment variables from .env files load to server. check this out: [whats-the-difference-between-exposing-environment-variables-in-nextjs-through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70764556/whats-the-difference-between-exposing-environment-variables-in-nextjs-through-t/70766460#70766460)

You have to define your env variable

```
  NEXT_PUBLIC_STRIPE_API_KEY=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

then use it in `getStripe`:

```
stripePromise = loadStripe(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRIPE_API_KEY);
```

Comment: I have the same problem and having the coe stripePromise = loadStripe(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRIPE_API_KEY) still does not initialize stripe on production. works fine in local dev enviornment. And yes I've double checked that the env variables are set correctly in my host provider

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to add the NEXT.js suffix to the public key in your getStripe.ts file, like this:

```
stripePromise = loadStripe(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY}`);
```

Then push your changes (don't merge them yet).

In vercel, add your environment variables under the "Project Settings" tab, and select the environment where you want to expose them (Preview/Development/Production).

Finally, redeploy your branch. This will create a new deployment, but with the newest configuration from your Project Settings, meaning your new environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

It's not mandatory to send API key by header, I think you are having problem with `const stripe = new Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);` and **process.env** is not loading `.env` variables you need to check if it's working and if not have to configure `dotenv`
FOR `NestJs API` you can see [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77394982/21212482)

Answer (score 0):

it works in my case: just add this in head of server file
`const env = require("dotenv").config({ path: "./.env" });`
or with import ES:

````
import dotenv from "dotenv";
const env = dotenv.config({ path: "./.env" });```
in any case, file names in .env must begin with REACT_APP_... for react + vite
````