# Nestjs cant resolve dependencies

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs

Can't figure out what's the problem of my code. (I'm new with nestjs, I'm trying to learn it by passing some apps to it). Console log says:

> Nest can't resolve dependencies of the UrlsAfipService (?). Please
>   make sure that the argument at index [0] is available in the ApiModule
>   context.

**UrlsAfipService**

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AfipUrls } from './urls'

@Injectable()
export class UrlsAfipService {

  constructor(
    private readonly afipUrls: AfipUrls,
  ) {}

  getWSAA () {
    return this.afipUrls.homo().wsaa; // <- change to prod() for production
  }

  getService (service: string) {
    return this.afipUrls.homo().service.replace('{service}', service)
  }
}
```

**AfipUrls**

```
export class AfipUrls {
    homo() {
      return {
        wsaa: 'https://url.com',
        service: 'https://url.com'
      }
    }

    prod() {
      return {
        wsaa: 'url.com',
        service: 'url.com'
      }
    }
}
```

**ApiModule**

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ApiController } from './api.controller';
import { UrlsAfipService } from './urls-afip.service'
import { WsaaService } from './wsaa.service'
import { DescribeService } from './describe.service';

@Module({
  controllers: [ApiController],
  providers: [UrlsAfipService, WsaaService, DescribeService]
})

export class ApiModule {}
```

**AppModule**

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';

import { ApiModule } from './api/api.module';

import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';

@Module({
  imports: [ApiModule],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})

export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared `AfipUrls` as a dependency for `UrlsAfipService` but it is not provided in any module.

So you have to add `AfipUrls` to the `providers` array of your `ApiModule`. Then it can be injected.

```
providers: [UrlsAfipService, WsaaService, DescribeService, AfipUrls]
//                                                         ^^^^^^^^
```

---

Note though, that encoding environment specific values in your code base might be a code smell. Consider creating a `ConfigService` that encapsulates environment specific variables that are read from environment variables or `.env` files using `dotenv`. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54364907/4694994) for more information.